# Highstock calendar - language used

Tags: highcharts

On the stock-tools-gui chart demo in here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/stock-tools-gui the months names in the calendar are displayed in English while months names in the date picker are in user's language (in my case in Polish based on my browser's locale).

Is there a way of the month name displayed along with user's browser's locale? I would prefer not to translate it manually through

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang:
```

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: As you mentioned it's located in local setting in browser, from Highcharts position you don't have options to set language of native browser dataPicker language.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus I was referring to opposite. I am happy with the fact that datePicker is in native browser language (Polish for me) and I would like to have month name in the view of Highcharts range selector to be shown in native browser language and format - so for me "25 Sty 2021" instead of "Jan 25, 2021" as seen on the printscreen above.

Comment: Strange cos the dataPicker is not a highcharts element whose range ends with `.highcharts-input-group`, after that it depends on the browser settings. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nz50Ldjt/)